# Git alias with #

Tags: git, shell, escaping, comments, alias

I was trying to create an alias with # in it and found I can't.

Alias:

```
ignored = !sh -c -e -v "cat .gitignore .git/info/exclude $HOME/.config/git/ignore | grep     -v `#` | grep ."
```

I already found a MUCH better way to do this (`find -type f  | git check-ignore --stdin` - gives files ignored in the repo, not just patterns) but am still curious how could I avoid git thinking "oh, it's a # the rest must be a comment" and ignoring it. I tried various quoting (backtics, double and single quotes, slash) but nothing worked. In shell, the command works of course.

So, the question: how to use a hash in a git config file in a shell (`sh -c` or a function) alias so that it's actually NOT treated as a comment?

Comment: What's wrong with just `git ls-files --exclude-standard --ignored`?

Comment: @jthill it's per current dir, not per whole repo. Meaning, if I don't remember about it, I will have partial info only. Also, it lacks `-o` (`--others`) to show untracked. As you wrote it, it gives me empty output most of the time. Finally, it's not for ignored files only. It's for listing the files. I can see which pattern causes the ignore and where it's coming from with `check-ignored` by adding a simple `-v` - easy to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following variant works for me:

```
ignored = !"cat .gitignore .git/info/exclude $HOME/.config/git/ignore | grep -v '#' | grep ."
```

I.e., no 3rd shell, and single quotes around `#`.

Comment: Yes, it works! Argh. I feel so stupid now. No 3rd shell indeed. Much obliged @phd, for the enlightenment. <bows>